# Touchpad not working after kernel upgrade to 4.4.0-57 on 16.04.1

Tags: 16.04, kernel, mouse, touchpad, dell

I have Ubuntu 16.04.1 LTS on Dell Inspiron 15R running for months as a fresh installation.

Days ago upgraded my Kernel to 4.4.0-57 through the PPA as found it as an update, and everything was OK for the first boot after it.

After that, Touchpad get working and stop working in random way with each boot, although external USB mouse is always working !

Just tried to boot the older kernel I have ( 4.4.0-47 ) and touchpad is working perfectly !

Is it an issue with the new Kernel ? some driver maybe ?

Thank You.

Comment: There was a problem with the ALPS/Synaptics driver for some Dells that was introduced with a kernel change last (2016) summer. The kernel patch was developed by the Synaptics maintainers around Halloween. It looks like it made it to 16.04 LTS this month (December 2016)...because I have been working around in on my Precision 7510 since October and it broke again this week. My solution was to add the Synaptics driver config files back in to /usr/share/X11/xconf.d/*. And by 'solution' I mean it works but I'm still tweaking settings.

Comment: To see which drivers your laptop is using try `xinput list-devices`.

Comment: OK, This is what I got:

Comment: ⎜   ↳ SynPS/2 Synaptics TouchPad               id=11 [slave  pointer  (2)]

Comment: @benrudgers, Seems it is the driver You mentioned, right ?

Comment: That seems like it could be right. Was that with the new kernel or older kernel?

Comment: @benrudgers, That was with the new kernel, and the surprise that it is working now with the new one, and not working with the old one !

Comment: @benrudgers, Can Windows 10 ( Dual Boot ) usage affect that somehow ? Is it possible that Windows is changing something in the toucpad device, making the drivers which Ubuntu is using not capable of dealing with Touchpad ?

Comment: I doubt Windows is affecting it, particularly if Ubuntu is running on a Linux native file system because Windows does not *usuall* read and write Linux native file systems (ext3, ext4) . Glad it is working.

Comment: @benrudgers, I agree with You that Windows won't probably modify Linux file system, but I think it might be modifying the touchpad device itself ? Is that possible ?

Comment: Possible sure. But likely, no. I'd say it's extremely unlikely. More likely is flakey behavior by Linux after playing around with different kernels and going backward and then forward again. The only way Windows could modify the touchpad hardware is by modifying the BIOS and as a general rule Windows does not do that.

Comment: @benrudgers, Can't modify the device itself ? I think Toucpad is a character device, which accept writing to and reading from ? not sure if that is correct.